# How to setup envs in neovim DAP configs for dotnet c#?

Tags: debugging, .net-core, vscode-debugger, neovim, coreclr

I am trying to **debug** my **c#** app with **neovim DAP**. Here is my **configs**:

```
local dap = require('dap')

dap.adapters.coreclr = {
  type = 'executable',
  command = '/home/asd/netcoredbg/netcoredbg',
  args = { '--interpreter=vscode' },
}

dap.configurations.cs = {
  {
    type = "coreclr",
    name = "launch - netcoredbg",
    request = "launch",
    program = function()
      -- return vim.fn.input('Path to dll', vim.fn.getcwd() .. '/bin/Debug/', 'file')
      return vim.fn.input('Path to dll: ')
    end
  },
}
```

When i run DAP with my dll, **I get these errors**:
[image]

I **tried** to use `netcoredbg` cli tool **separately**, like this: `~/netcoredbg/netcoredbg --interpreter=cli -- dotnet run ./bin/Debug/net7.0/WebApi.dll environment=DevelopmentLocalhost` and **everything works fine**.

**So i pretty sure that my dap configs are wrong.** Thanks for help!

**UPD:** I answered my actual question below. **BUT!** The last question remains: **is there a way to setup `dap` to just use `launch.json` generated by `VsCode` and how to do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I get it working with configs like this:

```
...
    justMyCode = false,
    stopAtEntry = false,
    program = function()
      -- todo: request input from ui
      return "/path/to/your.dll"
    end,
    env = {
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = function()
        -- todo: request input from ui
        return "Development"
      end,
      ASPNETCORE_URLS = function()
        -- todo: request input from ui
        return "http://localhost:5050"
      end,
    },
    cwd = function()
        -- todo: request input from ui
        return vim.fn.getcwd()
    end,
...
```

So **key thing here** is that we pass envs using `env` property of `cs` config object. Just like other fields it can be exact value, or can be a function where we can e.g. get input from ui and then use as a value for env variable:

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "Development"
```

or

```
ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = function()
   return vim.fn.input("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: ", "Development")
end,
```

**Also, its important to set `cwd`**, e.g. because `appsettings.json` will be searched there

```
cwd = function()
   return vim.fn.input("Workspace folder: ", vim.fn.getcwd() .. "/", "file")
end,
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**